# Javascript function scope concepts

Tags: javascript

I am reading this book "Secrets of the Javascript Ninja" where most of the code is demonstrated with the use of a custom assert. The code is as follows:

```
(function () {
    var queue = [],
        paused = false,
        results;

    this.test = function test(name, fn) {
        queue.push(function () {
            results = document.getElementById("results");
            results = assert(true, name).appendChild(
            document.createElement("ul"));
            fn();
        });
        runTest();
    };

    this.pause = function () {
        paused = true;
    };

    this.resume = function () {
        paused = false;
        setTimeout(runTest, 1);
    };

    function runTest() {
        if (!paused && queue.length) {
            queue.shift()();
            if (!paused) {
                resume();
            }
        }
    }

    this.assert = function assert(value, desc) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.className = value ? "pass" : "fail";
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(desc));

        if (results === undefined) results = document.getElementById("results");

        results.appendChild(li);

        if (!value) li.parentNode.parentNode.className = "fail";

        return li;
    };
})();
```

As you can see is a self invoking function.

I've been playing with it and something that I just cannot understand is why if, between the same  tags, I do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    ... previously shown code ...

    window.onload = function(){
       assert(true, "this works");
    };

</script>
```

And then again if I just do the assert like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    ... previously shown code ...
    assert(true, "this does not work");

</script>
```

When I try to execute the assert without using the window.onload event I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' to null" on the line "results.appendChild(li)" of the assert method.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I haven't really used assert function, but my guess (from the error message) is that it tries to use the DOM, so it will fail if used when it (the DOM) is not ready.

Comment: You know what the onload event is good for? The assert code executes a `document.getElementById` and tries to append to it - when the DOM is not already loaded this fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element markup (with `id="results"`) is not parsed by the time the code runs, so trying to fetch it with `getElementById` returns `null`, which in turn makes the `.appendChild` fail.

When you put your code inside the `window.onload` handler, it's (the code inside the handler function) guaranteed to run only after the window has been loaded at which point the document markup is fully parsed as well and  the element is available.

Alternatively, you can simply have your script element come after the target element:

```
<ul id="results"></ul>
<script>
//your code
</script>
```

Because the script element comes after the target element, the target element is guaranteed to exist by the time the script runs.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling the code before the elements on the page are rendered. So when the code looks for `document.getElementById("results")` it finds nothing and returns null.